# Cython: power inferior to 1 crash Jupyter kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cython

I'm computing the Total Variation inside a Cython function in Jupyter Notebook/Python 3.6 :

```
%%cython --compile-args=-O3 --compile-args=-fopenmp --link-args=-fopenmp

# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: cdivision=True
# cython: wraparound=False
# cython: profile=False

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython.parallel cimport parallel, prange

cdef extern from "stdlib.h":
    float abs(float x) nogil

cdef void p_norm(float[:, :, ::1] img, float[:, ::1] output, long p) nogil:
    cdef int M = img.shape[0]
    cdef int N = img.shape[1]
    cdef int i, j

    with parallel(num_threads=8):
        for i in prange(M, schedule="static"):
            for j in range(N):
                output[i, j] = (abs(img[i, j, 0]) ** p + abs(img[i, j, 1]) ** p) **(1/p)

def run_norm(a, output, p):
    return p_norm(a, output, p)
```

And computing the TV norm for p < 1

```
a = np.ascontiguousarray(np.arange(2*2048**2).reshape((2048, 2048, 2)), dtype=np.float32)
out = np.empty((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]), dtype=np.float32)
run_norm(a, out, 0.5)
```

makes the Jupyter kernel crash with no error. Changing

```
# cython: cdivision=False
```

makes it run indefinitely.

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it… It was the 1/p division in the power… Replacing by 1./p did the trick (float division) and p should have been a float type.